# Remove CustomTaskPane from window

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

For an addin for out look a new Custom task pane is added to a specific window using the following code:

```
historyPane = new HistoryPane(taskId);
customTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(historyPane, title, new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().ActiveWindow());
```

Now I want to be able to close this customTaskpane again for the specific window, I've searched far and wide, unfortunately without any success. 
I am unable to find a task pane in an active window. I've tried looking for some unique ID for a window or something to link to a dictionary and close it this way, also without any luck.
Would anyone be able to help me or point me in the good direction?

Comment: find ctp by window :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Remove` or `RemoveAt` methods of the `CustomTaskPanes` class.

```
public void RemoveTaskPaneWithTitle()
{
    for (int i = this.CustomTaskPanes.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        ctp = this.CustomTaskPanes[i - 1];
        if (ctp.Title == "Your title")
        {
             this.CustomTaskPanes.RemoveAt(i - 1);
        }
     }
  }
```

Also you may consider hiding the pane using the `Visible` property.

Read more about possible options in the [Managing Task Panes in Multiple Word and InfoPath Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264456%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it hides all CustomTaskPanes on every window, where I just want to close it on a specific window.

Comment: You can associate a custom task pane instance with a window handle (ID), so you could recognize which one must be closed.